# why env -i does not match the command manual

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables, env

I have read the linux command `env` manual, specifically, for the `-i` option, the manual says:

> -i, --ignore-environment  # start with an empty environment

What I get is that when `-i` option is specified, the environment is empty,i.e, no environment variable is there, so the command `env -i ls` should print something like **command not found** , but what I see is the command executes successfully. So please explain, do I misunderstand anything?

Answer (score 2):

> I think it better to read the source code to find out whether the OS
>   PATH variable persists through a clearing of environment – Tracy

Reading the source code would of course give all information about the matter. But we can also obtain valuable clues by using `strace`:

```
>strace -eexecve env -i ls       
execve("/usr/bin/env", ["env", "-i", "ls"], [/* 48 vars */]) = 0
execve("ls", ["ls"], [/* 0 vars */])    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/bin/ls", ["ls"], [/* 0 vars */]) = 0
```

We see that `env` tries executing `"ls"` without a path first, which fails, and then tries executing `"/bin/ls"`, which succeeds. We also see it *start with an empty environment* `[/* 0 vars */]`.

```
>strace -eexecve env -i foo  
execve("/usr/bin/env", ["env", "-i", "foo"], [/* 48 vars */]) = 0
execve("foo", ["foo"], [/* 0 vars */])  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/bin/foo", ["foo"], [/* 0 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/bin/foo", ["foo"], [/* 0 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
env: foo: No such file or directory
```

When specifying a non-existent command or a command residing in some other path, we see that `env` finally tries the `/usr/bin/` path, and that's it. So, obviously `/bin/` and `/usr/bin/` are hardcoded in `env`, and with `-i` the command's environment is indeed empty. Another test:

```
>env -i strace ls
strace: ls: command not found
```

If `ls` is to be executed not directly by `env -i`, but indirectly thru another command, it is not found.

Comment: This question is quite old, but I would like to bring some precisions to your answer. `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are not "hardcoded in `env`", but returned by default by `confstr(_CS_PATH)`, used by `execvp` which is called by `env` (see `execvp` manpage).

Answer (score 0):

The environment refers to all of the shell variables you set in your .bashrc and .bash_profile on login. If you're compiling something, you may set the `CFLAGS` variable. If you've got something installed in a weird directory, you may do an `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/build/bin` to allow it to run without specifying its full path.

`env -i` clears all these user-set variables and gives you a blank environment, so you can, for example, test how a command works if you have none of these extra variables set.

Comment: As per your answer, `env -i` should clear all these user-set  variable, including `PATH` varibale, so the shell should not be able to locate where `ls` is, but the result did not match my thoughs.

Comment: Including *user additions* to the PATH variable. The base OS PATH variable (and I think everything you setup in /etc/skel) persists through a clearing of environment, so things like /bin, /usr/bin, and /usr/local/bin will persist.

Comment: I think it better to read the source code to find out whether the OS PATH variable persists through a clearing of environment